# predict new user using lightfm

Tags: python, data-science, recommendation-engine, lightfm

I want to give a recommendation to a new user using lightfm.

Hi, I've got model, interactions, item_features.
The new user is not in interactions and the only information of the new user is their ratings.(list of book_id and rating pairs)

I tried to use predict() or predict_rank(), but I failed to figure out how.
Could you please give me some advice?

Below is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roXTm.png) which raised ValueError..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: @novonimo thansk I added screenshot but don't know how to put it into my post directly...

Comment: thank you for your responsibility. It's better to use plain text inside of the question instead of images. If you can, edit your post and remove screenshots and copy/paste your code/error logs here. good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem,
What I did was

1. Created a user_features matrix (based on their preferences) using Dataset class

   ```
    dataset = Dataset()
    dataset.fit(user_ids,item_ids)
    user_features = build_user_features([[user_id_1,[user_features_1]],..], normalize=True)
   ```
2. Provide it during training along with interaction CSR

   ```
   model = LightFM(loss='warp')
   model = model.fit(iteraction_csr,
                 user_features=user_features)
   ```
3. Create user_feature matrix for new-user using their preference ( in
   my case genres )

   ```
   dataset.fit_partial(users=[user_id],user_features=total_genres)
   new_user_feature = [user_id,new_user_feature]
   new_user_feature = dataset.build_user_features([new_user_feature])
   ```
4. Now predict item rankings with new_user feature

   ```
   scores = model.predict(<new-user-index>, np.arange(n_items),user_features=new_user_feature)
   ```

This gives a pretty decent result for new users but is not as good as the pure CF model.

[This](https://github.com/tr1ten/Anime-Recommender-System/blob/main/HybridRecommenderSystem.ipynb) is how I implemented it.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for late check! Hope you best

Comment: what about if you want to predict recommendations for an existing user, is that posssible?

Comment: Thank you. Now I finally understood how to recommend to cold-start users.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/V-Sher/LightFm_HybridRecommenderSystem/blob/master/LightFM%20Worked%20Example.ipynb) worked for me. It explains the process of formatting new user features and generating predictions for them.

`fit_partial` can only be used if you want to resume model training from its current state when you have newer interaction data for **existing users and items**. When you have newer users/items, you should retrain the model.

The existing model can be used to generate predictions for newer users though, the link above explains the process.